# Returning json from .csv asset in nuxt api

Tags: json, csv, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Using Nuxt 3, I am struggling to do something that appears simple: I would like to get a list of restaurants from an api served by nuxt/nitro in order to use it on the client side. My original file, is a `.csv` file stored under `assets/`: `assets/list.csv`.

Here is what I have in my component `.vue`file:

```
//...
const { restaurants } = await useFetch('/api/restaurants')
//...
```

And the content of `server/api/restaurants.js`:

```
import csv from 'csvtojson'

export default defineEventHandler(async(event) => {  
    const data = await csv().fromFile('~/assets/list.csv')
    return { data }
})
```

But I get an error "[500] File does not exist". I've tried many variants but always get an error here or there. Could you help me figure out the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually solved by realizing the following:

- As [the doc](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/assets) suggests, the `assets/` directory is for assets that are processed by the bundler (Vite or Webpack). Nuxt won't serve files in the `assets/` directory unless `nuxt.config.ts` is configured with the appropriate loader (e.g. a csv loader). Hence the 500 error.
- Nuxt Content, on the other hand, is useful to automatically parse a .csv file located in the `content/` directory:

  - In `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
modules: ["@nuxt/content"]
```

- In the component `.vue` file, the following will expose the parsed csv in `data.body`:

```
const { data } = await useAsyncData("list", () => queryContent("/list").findOne())
```

The beauty of nuxt is that you don't need to import anything, it does it for you.